# setfacl does not work on files in tmp

Tags: bash, debian, acl

```
ls -ld /tmp 
drwxrwxrwt 17 root root 440 Feb  3 11:18 /tmp

user1@debian:/tmp$ touch acltest0
user1@debian:/tmp$ ls -l acltest0 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Feb  3 11:22 acltest0

user1@debian:/tmp$ getfacl -c acltest0 
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--

user1@debian:/tmp$ setfacl -m u:user100:rw acltest0 
user1@debian:/tmp$ getfacl -c acltest0
user::rw-
user:user100:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

so far, so good... But:

```
user100@debian:/tmp$ echo 'edit from user100' >> acltest0 
bash: acltest0: Permission denied
```

ok I try:

```
vi acltest0

[...]

edit from user100
```

then

```
:wq
"acltest0"                                                                          
E212: Can't open file for writing: permission denied
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

ok I try:

```
:w!
```

I get the same error message.

why such an error message?

additional infos:

```
root@debian:/tmp# cat /etc/debian_version 
12.2

root@debian:/tmp# uname -a
Linux debian 6.1.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.55-1 (2023-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

thankx folks!

Comment: [`protected_regular`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691460/108618)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: That's right on the mark.